# Java Memory game

Tags: java

I would like to make a game in java. The game is memory game that show all the cards when the game start, then flip all the cards when click, then for every click it reveal one card at a time so that.

1. if 2 cards are the same the remain visible
2. if the 2 cards are not the same they flip back

i am only 2 weeks old form java point of view so please try to be as clear as possible.

here is what i achieved so fare  and i am stuck to make the cards flip when i click.

I use processing library. any help would be appreciated.

```
package cards;
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class MemoryGame extends PApplet {

Card[] cards;

public void setup() {
    size(1260, 600); 
    cards = new Card[6];
    cards[0] = new Card(11, 0, 0);
    cards[1] = new Card(3, Card.WIDTH, 0);
    cards[2] = new Card(7, 2 * Card.WIDTH, 0);
    cards[3] = new Card(3, 0, Card.HEIGHT);
    cards[4] = new Card(7, Card.WIDTH, Card.HEIGHT);
    cards[5] = new Card(11, 2 * Card.WIDTH, Card.HEIGHT);

}

public void draw() {
    background(204);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cards[i].display(this);
    }
}

public void mousePressed() {
         for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cards[i].display(this);
    }
             }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PApplet.main("cards.MemoryGame");
}
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++Card Class++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
package cards;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Card {

boolean shown=false;
static final int WIDTH = 120;
static final int HEIGHT = 180;
static final int gap = 20;
int value;
float x;
float y;

Card(int _v, float _x, float _y) {

    value = _v;
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
}

public void display(PApplet applet) {
    if (shown) {
        applet.fill(0);
        applet.rect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    } else {
        applet.fill(255);
        applet.rect(x, y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }
}

public void flip() {
    shown=!shown;
}
}
```

Comment: And what's your question, 2 weeks old OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change mousePressed() to:

```
public void mousePressed() {
         for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        //first flip cards
        cards[i].flip();

        //then display them
        cards[i].display(this);
    }
```

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot.

Now i am trying to modify this so that when i click on one card only that card flip instead of all of them. Is that possible ?